# read() for reading stream from stdin

Tags: c, linux, stream, stdout, stdin

I am trying to write a C code (running on a Ubuntu Linux OS), which reads from stdin continuously, and receiving varying length of bytes each time. It needs to send back to stdout in 15-bytes-long arrays, whenever the receive buffer reaches or exceeds 15 each time.

**Draft Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  char buff[100];

  // Round 1
  read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, 15);
  printf("Part 1:%s", buff);

  // Round 2
  read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, 15);
  printf("Part 2:%s", buff);

  return 0;
}
```

To give an example with a scenario. We are receiving 30 bytes, in 3 batches and 10 bytes for each time. I used 3 echo commands to represent this in below example scenario.

Also adding expected output, and actual output of current draft code. Any comment or suggestion to have the expected output (maybe another function rather than read and printf ?), would be appreciated.

**Scenario**

Terminal 1:

```
mkfifo /tmp/MyPipe
tail -f /tmp/MyPipe | ./StreamProcess
```

Terminal 2:

```
echo -ne '1234567890' >> /tmp/MyPipe
echo -ne 'abcdefghij' >> /tmp/MyPipe
echo -ne 'qwertyuiop' >> /tmp/MyPipe
```

**Expected output on Terminal 1**

After 1st echo: Nothing is printed

After 2nd echo:

```
Part 1:1234567890abcde
```

After 3rd echo:

```
Part 1:1234567890abcdePart 2:fghijqwertyuiop
```

**Current output (with draft code) on Terminal 1**

After 1st echo: Nothing is printed

After 2nd echo:

```
Part 1:1234567890s·     s·Part 2:abcdefghijs·   s·
```

After 3rd echo: (only the $ prompt is printed)

```
Part 1:1234567890s·     s·Part 2:abcdefghijs·   s·$
```

Comment: This is operating system specific (you probably use POSIX or Linux). Read about [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and edit your question to improve it (at least by telling on which OS you are coding)

Comment: 1) `char buff[100];` buff is not initialised 2)  `read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, 15);` read returns a value. Use it!
3)  `printf("Part 1:%s", buff);` buff is not necessarily nul-terminated. Also: add a '\n' to the format string.
`

Comment: @wildplasser Is the buffer not pre-initialized unless it's in global scope? My understanding is that null terminators need to be placed, but the buffer need not be zeroed.

Comment: the question says the read/write operation is continuous but the code only reads a max of 30 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

given the criteria listed in the question, the following code will perform the desired operation.

Edit: incorporated comments to question.

Edit: added error checking

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(), STDIN_FILENO. perror()
#include <unistd.h>  // read(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define MAX_READ_LEN 15

int main( void)
{
    char buff[ MAX_READ_LEN+1 ];
    int partNum = 0;

    while( 1 )
    {
        // Round 1
        ssize_t bytesRead = read( STDIN_FILENO, buff, MAX_READ_LEN );

        if( 0 > bytesRead )
        {
            perror( "read failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, read successful

        buff[ bytesRead ] = '\0';
        partNum++;
        printf("Part %d:%s\n", partNum, buff);
    }

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added "#include <stdlib.h>" to top.
Output:
Part 1:1234567890
Part 2:abcdefghij
Part 3:qwertyuiop

Comment: @JimRaynor, why add that statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`?  Nothing in my answer nor in your posted code needs anything from that header file.